# Enable link after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

> **Requirements:**

When I clicked first time on menu item which has dropdown menu, It should show its dropdown and when I clicked on the same menu item second time it will redirect to its own page.
**Please consider the situation. Menu item redirect to its own page only when its dropdown are opens**

> **Reference Images:**

[image: hello]

[image]

> **Reference website link:**

[Reference website link](http://demo83.com/mobile_menu/)

> **Note for referaence website:**

**1) Please open reference website link on mobile view.

2) Click on about page than Dental Page and than again About page , When you second time clicked on about page It goes to its own page. But on this occasion I want to open its dropdown and again If I clicked About page than it goes to its own page**

Currently I am using **jQuery bind** function and disable link through **event.preventDefault()** but i didn't resolve my problem 
Here's my code

> **jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flexnav li.parent-menu-item > a").bind("click.myclick", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".flexnav li .sub-menu").hide();
        $(this).unbind(".myclick");
        $(this).parents(".flexnav li.parent-menu-item").children(".sub-menu").toggle();
    }); 
});
```

**Sorry for my language mistakes
Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the click event inside the $(document).ready function, you should try doing it inline with each li.

```
<li id="link1" onclick="ShowMenu('#menu1', 'index.html')">
  <ul class="dropdown" id="menu1">
    ...
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="link2" onclick="ShowMenu('#menu2', 'aboutus.html')">
  <ul class="dropdown" id="menu2">
    ...
  </ul>
</li>

<script>
  function ShowMenu(menuId, linkRef){
    var display = $(menuID).css('display');
    if(display == 'block')
      window.location.href = linkRef;
    else{
      $('dropdwon').hide();          
      $(menuId).show();
    }
  }
</script>
```

So, here, what I am doing is to call the ShowMenu() function with the id of the menu I want to show, as the parameter and the url of the page linked to it.
The function then checks if that menu is being displayed or not. If being displayed then it redirects the user to the url. If not, then it proceeds to hide all other dropdowns and shows only the one that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS class toggle to see if the dropdown is open or not and perform the action accordingly. (Assuming your current code is working fine to open dropdown)

```
$("body").on("click",".flexnav li.parent-menu-item > a",function(e){
   var dropdowns=$(this).parent('li').children(".sub-menu");
   var menu=$(this).parents(".flexnav li.parent-menu-item").children(".sub-menu");
   if(dropdowns.size()>0) {
       if(!menu.hasClass('open')) {
           e.preventDefault();
           menu.addClass('open');
           menu.show();
       }
   }
});
```